# Does ampersand of reference data type return the address of the reference itself or the value it is referencing?

Tags: c++

I wish I could have tested it myself, but unfortunately it's impossible to do so in the current situation I'm in. Could anyone care to shed some light on this?

Comment: Please formulate the question in a concrete code example.

Comment: Reference when passing to function?

Comment: The question's fairly clear, no? A reference is a reference, no matter where it is, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike a pointer, a reference isn't actually an object. It doesn't have an address itself, it's easier to think of it as an alias to an object that the compiler will then interpret.

Anyway, you can always test code online with [IdeOne](http://ideone.com/)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(int &z)
{
    printf("&z: %p", &z);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int x = 0;
    int &y = x;

    printf("&x: %p\n", &x);
    printf("&y: %p\n", &y);

    func(x);

    return 0;
}
```

[Executed online, with results](http://ideone.com/sX0zd).

Comment: It's pretty brilliant :) You'll love it.

Comment: It is unspecified whether or not a reference requires storage, so it may be an object (§8.3.2/4). Expressions applied to a reference are, however, forwarded to the referenced object (§5/5)

Comment: You're right. I didn't know whether or not to mention overloaded address operators in my post.

Answer (score 5):

It returns the address of the value it is referencing.

Answer (score 1):

Address of the value.
(There is no such thing as address of reference)

You can always check on codepad : http://codepad.org/I1aBfWAQ

Answer (score 1):

A further experiment: there are online compilers that allow inspection of intermediate results!

Taking Mahmoud's example on the Try out LLVM and Clang page, we get the following LLVM IR (truncated).

```
define i32 @main() nounwind uwtable {
  %x = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 0, i32* %x, align 4, !tbaa !0
  %1 = call i32 (i8*, ...)* @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([8 x i8]* @.str, i64 0, i64 0), i32* %x)
  %2 = call i32 (i8*, ...)* @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([8 x i8]* @.str1, i64 0, i64 0), i32* %x)
  %3 = call i32 (i8*, ...)* @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([7 x i8]* @.str2, i64 0, i64 0), i32* %x) nounwind
  ret i32 0
}
```

... the syntax is not too important, what is important is to note that a single variable has been declared: `%x` (whose name is suspiciously similar to that of the C function).

This means that the compiler has elided the `y` and `z` variable, no storage is ever allocated for them.

I will spare you the assembly listing ;)

Comment: Beat me to it :) I was going to go home and see if there's an actual object being created somewhere in the intermediate object code. Now I just have to figure out an example complicated enough for an object to be created (if ever). +1

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi: A function argument should be generated. Even if the function is inlined, unless it is static Clang will emit its definition because it might be used by another translation unit.

Comment: Yep. The sample code in my post results in this LLVM bytecode: http://pastebin.com/bZ4PZvup exactly as you predicted.